Excel not responding sometime after running for loop
I have a code that uses multiple Excel to copy the data from one Excel sheet to a new Excel sheet, everything is running fine until the code goes into FOR loop, I've tried to run the loop to 50 iterations, but it was running fine, with runtime for tens of seconds, but when I ran the loop for whole 1000 iterations, my excel is not responding after 4-5 mins. can you please let me know where I'm going wrong?
Sub automation_p1()

Dim WB2 As Workbook, WB3 As Workbook
Dim Ws1 As Worksheet, Ws2 As Worksheet, Ws3 As Worksheet
Dim MyRng As Range, MyRng1 As Range, lR As Long, lR1 As Long
Dim openfile As String, En As String
Dim strFile As String, Path As String, dt As String
Dim A As Variant


Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

En = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
Path = En & "\Desktop\"
 
strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(strFile, UpdateLinks:=True)
Set Ws2 = WB2.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set WB3 = Workbooks.Add
Set Ws3 = WB3.Sheets("Sheet1")
''Ws3.Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    WB2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    
    Set MyRng = Ws2.Range("A6:AJ6").Find("Order No")
   
    If Not MyRng Is Nothing Then
        lR = Ws2.Cells(Ws2.Rows.Count, MyRng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Ws2.Range(Ws2.Cells(6, MyRng.Column), Ws2.Cells(lR, MyRng.Column)).Copy
        Ws3.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
    
    Set MyRng = Ws2.Range("A6:AJ6").Find("Priority No.")
   
    If Not MyRng Is Nothing Then
        lR = Ws2.Cells(Ws2.Rows.Count, MyRng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Ws2.Range(Ws2.Cells(6, MyRng.Column), Ws2.Cells(lR, MyRng.Column)).Copy
        Ws3.Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    
    Set MyRng = Ws2.Range("A6:AJ6").Find("Cust Name")
   
    If Not MyRng Is Nothing Then
        lR = Ws2.Cells(Ws2.Rows.Count, MyRng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Ws2.Range(Ws2.Cells(6, MyRng.Column), Ws2.Cells(lR, MyRng.Column)).Copy
        Ws3.Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

    Set MyRng = Ws2.Range("A6:AJ6").Find("Cust Name")
   
    If Not MyRng Is Nothing Then
        lR = Ws2.Cells(Ws2.Rows.Count, MyRng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Ws2.Range(Ws2.Cells(6, MyRng.Column), Ws2.Cells(lR, MyRng.Column)).Copy
        Ws3.Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    
    Set MyRng = Ws2.Range("A6:AJ6").Find("Balance Value LCY")
   
    If Not MyRng Is Nothing Then
        lR = Ws2.Cells(Ws2.Rows.Count, MyRng.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        Ws2.Range(Ws2.Cells(6, MyRng.Column), Ws2.Cells(lR, MyRng.Column)).Copy
        Ws3.Range("D1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

WB3.Activate
WB3.Sheets.Add
lR = WB3.Sheets(1).Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row '' lR =1000

WB2.Close savechanges = False


strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set WB1 = Workbooks.Open(strFile, UpdateLinks:=True)
Set Ws1 = WB1.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    WB3.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete

For i = 2 To lR ''running loop to find the value from Workbook3 WB3(sheet1) to workbook2 (WB2 sheet1)
    A = WB3.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value
    WB1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate

    Set MyRng = WB1.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A11:XFC11").Find(A)
    
    If Not MyRng Is Nothing Then
        If Not WB1.ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
                WB1.ActiveSheet.Range("A11:XFC11").AutoFilter
        End If
        ActiveSheet.Range("A11:XFC11").AutoFilter Field:=MyRng.Column, Criteria1:="<>", Criteria2:="<>FALSE"
        ActiveSheet.Cells(MyRng.Row, MyRng.Column).Select
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Copy
        
        WB3.Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
        Set MyRng1= wb3.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:XFC1")
            IF  MyRng1.Rows.Count=0 Then
                Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            Else
                Range("A1").Select
                Selection.End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            End IF
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        WB1.Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
        
Next i

strFile = "Sara File"
dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh_mm")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Path & strFile & " " & dt

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Thanks in advance

Select and Activate take more resource and slow down the code execution.
How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA

thanks for the advice, I removed Select and Activate as much as possible but again my code is not responding after few minutes.

Pls share the latest code in your post.

Hi sorry for the late response, now the code executed within 2-3 minutes now, I checked last row was taking the full column value 1048576, I've adjusted the code it's working good

@Toddler If you think this can be useful for others, feel free to write an answer to your question explaining the adjustment you made.
